# Streaming over Azure API Management

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-web-api, stream, azure-api-management

I'm using streaming approach to emulate real-time communication between server and clients. It works ok when I get stream directly from web api. But when I try to receive messages over azure api management it returns pack of messages for last ~20 minutes.
It's web api method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("subscribe/{subscription}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Subscribe(string subscription)
    {
        PushStreamContent eventStream = new PushStreamContent(delegate (Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context)
        {
            Subscribe(subscription, stream);
        }, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/event-stream"));
        HttpResponseMessage message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        message.Content = eventStream;

        return message;
    }
```

And to get stream I send XMLHttpRequest from google chrome console:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('get', 'https://{api}.azure-api.net/subscribe/hi', true)
request.setRequestHeader('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key','{subscription_key}')
request.onabort = function() { console.log('abort') }
request.onerror = function() { console.log('error') }
request.onprogress = function(e) { console.log(e) }
request.onload = function() { console.log('done') }
request.send()
```

So is it possible to configure azure API management somehow to return messages on stream Flush() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment but we will add support for streaming scenarios soon. We will post the announcement to the [update feed](http://aka.ms/apimdocs).